# Do you have a list of books about the evolution of the banking sector?

Tags: reference-request, banking, central-banking, federal-reserve

I'm looking for interesting books to read about the banking sector.

**Topics**:

- Changes in the banking sector,
- Adaptation of financial services in the digital age,
- European and US banking regulations
- The efficiency of banking supervision,
- Convergence of banking and insurance sector.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

**French/français :**

Avez-vous une liste de livres au sujet de l'évolution du secteur bancaire ?

Je suis à la recherche de livres intéressants à lire au sujet de l'économie bancaire.

Sujets possibles :

- évolution du secteur bancaire,
- l'adaptation des services financiers à l'ère numérique,
- réglementations bancaires européennes et américaines,
- l'efficience de la supervision bancaire,
- convergence du secteur bancaire et assurantiel.

Je vous remercie par avance de vos propositions.

Comment: It may be 143 years old, but Walter Bagehot's *Lombard Street: A Description of the Money Market* is still relevant to the operation of banking, liquidity and central banking.  For something similar but more up to date you could try Perry Mehrling's *The New Lombard Street:  How the Fed became the Dealer of Last Resort*

Comment: I also like Gorton's "Misunderstanding Financial Crises" and obviously Friedman and Schwartz, "A Monetary History of the United States."

Comment: Thank you for your list. I look for new books and more specific about the changes in banking regulations and developments in the banking sector.                                                                                                             French/français : Je vous remercie pour votre liste. Je recherche des livres récents  et encore plus précis sur les évolutions des réglementations bancaires et les évolutions du secteur bancaire.